# How do I unit test a monkey patch in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, monkeypatching

I have a utility method that behaves like this

```
def my_patch_method(self):
    pass

def patch_my_lib():
    from mylib import MyClass
    MyClass.target_method = my_patch_method
    return MyClass()
```

This test fails:

```
self.assertEqual(my_patch_method, patch_my_lib().target_method)
```

Whereas this one works:

```
self.assertEqual(my_patch_method.__name__, patch_my_lib().target_method.__name__)
```

As the patch method does not have the same name, this is still acceptable proof that `patch_my_lib()` is doing what it's payed for but why doesn't the first work as I would expect ? And, is there a way to "fix" it ?

Comment: This is because `my_patch_method` is an unbound function, whereas `patch_my_lib().target_method` is a bound method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your first test fails is that once you monkey-patch the function into your class, it isn't really the same object any more.

```
>>> def foo(self): pass
... 
>>> class Foo: pass
... 
>>> Foo.bar = foo
>>> type(Foo.bar)
<type 'instancemethod'>
>>> type(foo)
<type 'function'>
>>> 
>>> Foo.bar is foo
False
>>> Foo.bar == foo
False
```

In fact, the original function and the new method have different types.  Instead, have your first test check this condition:

```
>>> Foo.bar.im_func is foo
True
```

So maybe this: `self.assertIs(my_patch_method, patch_my_lib().target_method.im_func)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for all these details.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
self.assertEqual(my_patch_method, patch_my_lib().target_method.im_func)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an instance from patch_my_lib, so comparing the function to the bound method

Something like this should pass

```
self.assertEqual(my_patch_method, patch_my_lib().target_method.im_func)
```

But it's probably better to check that the behaviour you are patching is working

Answer (score 0):

`MyClass.target_method = my_patch_method` sets your function as a class function for `MyClass`, but you return a instance of that class with `return MyClass()`.